# accessing the tokenized words in python

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have values in query column of a panda data frame which are tokenized using the split() function like

```
query[4] = "['rain', 'shower', 'head']".
```

Now I want to perform some operations on individual words. So, I converted it into list and iterated through it using for loop like like :

```
l=list(query[4])

for word in l : word=func(word)
```

But it is storing each alphabets on the list like - `['[', "'", 'r', 'a', 'i', 'n', "'", ','` and so on.

I have even tried to use join function i.e. - `''.join(word)` and `''.join(l)`

But still nothing is working for me. 
Can you suggest something here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python)

Comment: `list` does not parse the given string, it simply creates the list of string symbols. If you want to parse `"['rain', 'shower', 'head']"` take a look at the link above.

Comment: What is the command you ran on pandas DF to get this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert to string to actual list:

```
data = eval(query[4])
```

Then loop through the data:

```
for word in data: word = func(word)
```

Comment: [Is Using eval In Python A Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Yes.  So better use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

If need works with `pandas DataFrame`, you need first convert `string` values to `list` with [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':["[rain, shower, head]", "[rain1, shower1, head1]"]})
print (df)
                         a
0     [rain, shower, head]
1  [rain1, shower1, head1]

print (type(df.a.ix[0]))
<class 'str'>

df['a'] = df.a.str.strip('[]').str.split(',')
print (df)

                           a
0     [rain,  shower,  head]
1  [rain1,  shower1,  head1]

print (type(df.a.ix[0]))
<class 'list'>
```

Then you can apply custom function:

```
def func(x):
    return x + 'aaa'

def f(L):
    return [func(word) for word in L]

print (df.a.apply(f))    
0       [rainaaa,  showeraaa,  headaaa]
1    [rain1aaa,  shower1aaa,  head1aaa]
Name: a, dtype: object
```

---

```
def f(L):
    return [word + 'aaa' for word in L]

print (df.a.apply(f))    
0       [rainaaa,  showeraaa,  headaaa]
1    [rain1aaa,  shower1aaa,  head1aaa]
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the correct output. The line

```
query[4] = "['rain', 'shower', 'head']"
```

means that query[4] is of type string. To be treatable as array, it should be `['rain', 'shower', 'head']`.

Check this output from python REPL with what you have:

```
>>> query = "['rain', 'shower', 'head']"
>>> list(query)
>>> ['[', "'", 'r', 'a', 'i', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 's', 'h', 'o', 'w', 'e', 'r', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'h', 'e', 'a', 'd', "'", ']']
```

After changing the assignment to an array, here is the new output in REPL:

```
>>> query = ['rain', 'shower', 'head']
>>> list(query)
>>> ['rain', 'shower', 'head']
```

Comment: Yes, I understand it now. But can you suggest something what should I do here to get the desired output ?